# Unable to draw commutative diagram under amsart

Tags: commutative-diagrams

Here i attached the code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}

\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage{amsgen, amstext,amsbsy,
amsopn, amsthm, amsfonts,amssymb,
amscd,amsmath,euscript,enumerate,url,
verbatim,calc,xypic}

\usepackage{amscd}


\textwidth6.5in

\textheight9in

\oddsidemargin.2in

\evensidemargin.2in

\topmargin-1cm

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}%[theorem]

\newtheorem{defn}[theorem]{Definition}

\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}

\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}

\newtheorem{qns}[theorem]{Question}

\newtheorem{obs}[theorem]{Observation}

\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}%[section]

%\newtheorem{Exam}{Example}[section]

%\newtheorem{prop}{proposition}[section]

%\newtheorem{exer}{Exercise}[section]

\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}%[section]

%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}%[section]

\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}%[section]

\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}%[section]

\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb Q}

\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb Z}

\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb C}

\newcommand{\FF}{\mathbb F}

\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb R}

\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb N}

\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}

%\operatorname{deg}{{\deg}}

\newcommand{\irr}{\;\text{irr}\;}

\newcommand{\disc}{\:\text{disc}\;}

\newcommand{\ov}{\overline}

\newcommand{\sign}{\mbox{ sign }}

\newcommand{\gs}{\sigma}

\newcommand{\gt}{\tau}

\newcommand{\m}{\mathfrak m}

\newcommand{\Hom}{\mbox { Hom }}

\newcommand{\ga}{\alpha}

\newcommand{\gb}{\beta}

%\newcommand{\gg}{\gamma}

%\newcommand{\char}{\mbox{ char }}

\title[]{Algebra}

\author[]{Ripan Das}

\begin{document}

\maketitle




\newpage



\begin{tikzcd}

\cdots \arrow[r] & M_1 \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & M_2 \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & M_3 \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & \cdots \arrow[r] & M_n \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & {} \\
\cdots \arrow[r] & N_1 \arrow[r]           & N_2 \arrow[r]           & N_3 \arrow[r]           & \cdots \arrow[r] & N_n \arrow[r]           & {}
\end{tikzcd}


\[\begin{tikzcd}

    G & {G'} \\
    {G/H} & {}
    \arrow["f"', from=1-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow["\pi"', from=1-1, to=2-1]
    \arrow["g"', from=2-1, to=1-2]

\end{tikzcd}\]






\end{document}
```

this code runs in overleaf and produce a nice commutative diagram but in texmaker it cannot produce and shows only nodes but not the arrows.[image: Here I attached what I get in texstudio]

Comment: I also use different format like quiver, matrix but the results are same. Only under amscd I get some commutative rectangle but I want to do under tikz

Comment: `\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}` don't load  `epsfig` in any document written since 1994, and only use `[dvips]`if you are using dvips, not pdflatex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incompatible packages, *unless* you go the `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` route (which is possible on Overleaf, I believe). You also have blank lines in the `tikzcd` environment, which are not allowed.

To begin with, your preamble is a big mess. You're loading

- `epsfig`, which is only for compatibility with documents written before 1995
- `pstricks`, which requires compiling with `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`

You are also loading packages multiple times. For instance, `amsmath` appears twice and it automatically loads `amsgen`, `amstext`, `amsbsy` and `amsopn`. Besides, `amsmath` is also automatically loaded by the `amsart` class, together with an internal version of `amsthm`.

Using `enumitem` is nowadays much preferred over `enumerate`: are you really using its features? In this case, translating for `enumitem` is not difficult.

Loading `tikz` and the library `cd` is the same as loading `tikz-cd`.

I can't understand why loading `amscd`: it provides for very elementary diagrams, that can be better made with `tikz-cd`. There's no reason for loading also `xy` (not `xypic`) if all you need its `\xymatrix` feature for commutative diagrams.

Setting `\textheight` and so on in `amsart` is possible, but such settings *must* be followed by `\calclayout`.

The correct syntax for `\mathbb` is `\mathbb{A}`, not `\mathbb A` and similarly for `\mathfrak`. I also changed a few definitions to achieve better uniformity of spacing, notably `\irr` and `\disc`: notice `\mathrm` and not `\text`, because you want upright shape in every context.

By the way, LaTeX provides `\to` as shorthand for `\rightarrow`. No need to define `\ra`, that's much less transparent.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd,matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}

% for these you need latex+dvips+ps2pdf
% the last one with the -dALLOWTRANSPARENCY option
%\usepackage{pstricks}
%\usepackage{pst-node}

\usepackage{
  %amsmath,
  %amsthm,
  amssymb,
  euscript,
  %enumerate,% better enumitem
  url,
  verbatim,
  calc,
}


\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\calclayout
\linespread{1.2}

%\oddsidemargin.2in % wrong
%\evensidemargin.2in % wrong
%\topmargin-1cm % wrong


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}%[theorem]
\newtheorem{defn}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{qns}[theorem]{Question}
\newtheorem{obs}[theorem]{Observation}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}%[section]
%\newtheorem{Exam}{Example}[section]
%\newtheorem{prop}{proposition}[section]
%\newtheorem{exer}{Exercise}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}%[section]
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}%[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}%[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}%[section]

\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\FF}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}}

\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow} % isn't \to better than \ra?
\newcommand{\irr}{\mathrel{\mathrm{irr}}}
\newcommand{\disc}{\mathrel{\mathrm{disc}}}
\newcommand{\ov}{\overline}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}

\newcommand{\ga}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\gb}{\beta}
%\newcommand{\gg}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\gs}{\sigma}
\newcommand{\gt}{\tau}

\newcommand{\m}{\mathfrak{m}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}

\title[]{Algebra}

\author[]{Ripan Das}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{tikzcd}
\cdots \arrow[r] & M_1 \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & M_2 \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & M_3 \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & \cdots \arrow[r] & M_n \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & {} \\
\cdots \arrow[r] & N_1 \arrow[r]           & N_2 \arrow[r]           & N_3 \arrow[r]           & \cdots \arrow[r] & N_n \arrow[r]           & {}
\end{tikzcd}


\[\begin{tikzcd}
    G & {G'} \\
    {G/H} & {}
    \arrow["f", from=1-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow["\pi"', from=1-1, to=2-1]
    \arrow["g"', from=2-1, to=1-2]
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sir i actually doing latex for few days and I don't know very much basic things on it. I just know how to type a code and whenever I need something I just ask it online like this time and this preamble is written by my sir I just copy paste it in every file and started to write if I need some package I check it online and wrote it in preamble.

Comment: thank sir it works

Comment: is there any way to contact you for learning latex?

Answer (score 1):

First, your code doesn't compile because you can't have empty lines in a `tikzcd` environment. But even after those are removed, you don't get your desired result in Overleaf or elsewhere. The issue is all the packages you are loading.

Many of the packages you load are unnecessary.  For example, you are using `tikz-cd` to make your diagrams. You don't also need `cd`, `amscd`, or `xypic`. In general, don't load a package that you aren't using.

In this case, are you using the `epsfig` package? If so, you must load it *after* `tikz-cd` to avoid unintended consequences. If you are not using it, remove it. As @egreg points out, `epsfig` has been unnecessary for a very long time.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
\cdots \arrow[r] & M_1 \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & M_2 \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & M_3 \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & \cdots \arrow[r] & M_n \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & {} \\
\cdots \arrow[r] & N_1 \arrow[r]           & N_2 \arrow[r]           & N_3 \arrow[r]           & \cdots \arrow[r] & N_n \arrow[r]           & {}
\end{tikzcd}

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    G & {G'} \\
    {G/H} & {}
    \arrow["f"', from=1-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow["\pi"', from=1-1, to=2-1]
    \arrow["g"', from=2-1, to=1-2]
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The package `epsfig` should not be used in documents written after 1995. It only exists for compatibility with older documents.

Comment: @egreg: Sorry. Lost track of time.

Comment: I'd say that the issue is not `epsfig` by itself, but the `dvips` option.